# iOS SwiftUI: ObservableObject from parent to child

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

### Problem:

Passing down the view model and modifying it from the children, won't refresh the parent.

### What I want:

Whenever I modify the view model from the child view, the parent refresh too.

### Problem description:

I'm looking for a way to pass down a `ViewModel ObservedObject` to some child views.

This is my struct:

```
struct Parent: View {
    @ObservedObject viewModel: ViewModel

     var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                Form {
                    ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                         Section {
                            ChildViewOne(model: viewModel)
                        }
                        
                        Section {
                            ChildViewTwo(model: viewModel)
                        }
                        
                        Section {
                            ChildViewThree(model: viewModel)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}

struct AnyChild: View {
    @ObservedObject viewModel: ViewModel

     var body: some View {
            // some stuff
        }
}
```

In this way, whenever I modify from the child views the view model, the children rebuild correctly, but the parent won't, and the scrollview does not resize correctly.

I would like to pass down to the children the viewModel like a Binding object, so the parent will refresh too.

But I don't know how to do. Any help?

### Solution:

I had a specific problem with the `Form` when I've removed everything worked fine.

But still the correct solution as **@Alladinian** wrote is to use the  `@EnvironmentObject`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of passing the same model to each subview, you can use `@EnvironmentObject` instead which is specifically designed for this.

You essentially have to inject your `ObservableObject` in your parent view with something like this (typically in your appdelegate before presenting the parent view, or in your previews setup for live previewing):

```
Parent().environmentObject(ViewModel())
```

then you can automatically get a reference in each view with something like this:

```
struct AnyChild: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: ViewModel
    //...
}
```

and use it with your bindings

Here is a brief [article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views) about the use of environment

Finally, regarding why your solution is not working, you must consider a single source of truth (the observable object in your Parent) and a `@Binding` for each subview that will eventually change the state of this object. I hope that this makes sense...

Comment: I don't quite understand your comment, but if you mean why your solution doesn't work its because you should pass a binding to them not the observable object itself...

Comment: I've tried your solution, I'm still having the problem. If I change the size of the children and the father still won't refresh properly and the content is cut

Comment: the problem was the form, I've removed it and everything works

Comment: `@EnvironmentObject` seems like a glorified global variable. I'm surprised there's not a `@State` / `@Binding` analog for more complex objects